# ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database

Tags: oracle, weblogic12c, oracle-ords

I am seeing this issue frequently after I have implemented the ORDS in R12.2.9 upgrade. Our ORDS is hosted on a weblogic server this issue occurs when there are 10 connections updating a single table? Is there any setup for a maximum connection control?

Complete Error:
ORDS was unable to make a connection to the database.  This can occur if the database is unavailable, the maximum number of sessions has been reached or the pool is not correctly configured. The connection pool named: |apex|pu| had the following error(s): Exception occurred while getting connection: oracle.ucp.UniversalConnectionPoolException: All connections in the Universal Connection Pool are in use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error means the pool has been exhausted. 10 is the DEFAULT pool size, and is almost NEVER correct for a production deployment.

It's very likely a decently active application will use all 10 connection from a pool, resulting in the exact error you are seeing.

So the answer: increase the max connections property for your pool, and restart ORDS. The hard part is: based on your application performance and activity profile, how large should the pool be?

Some good advice can be found [here from our Real World Performance Team](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/21/jjucp/optimizing-real-world-performance.html#GUID-BC09F045-5D80-4AF5-93F5-FEF0531E0E1D).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `jdbc.MaxLimit` parameter when [configuring ORDS](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-rest-data-services/21.3/aelig/about-REST-configuration-files.html#GUID-37AA1468-DCB3-4D8B-868C-1910A0C04D68). It defaults to 10 as the maximum number of connections.

> jdbc.MaxLimit
>
> Specifies the maximum number of connections.
>
> Defaults to 10. (Might be too low for some production environments.)

Using a command like `java -jar ords.war set-property jdbc.MaxLimit 50` would set the maximum number of connections to 50 (after reloading ORDS or restarting WebLogic).

Comment: Hello sir , I tried this command to increase the MaxLimit but I got error Warning: Support for executing: java -jar ords.war has been deprecated. I have release 22.3 how to increase the limit and solve this issue ?

Comment: for newer versions of ORDS, you will need to use the ords executable in the bin directory instead of executing commands with the .war file. So your command should look something like `./ords set-property jdbc.MaxLimit 50`